# How can I modify the what string of a C++ runtime_error?

Tags: c++, exception, std, runtime-error

I have a class which inherits from `std::runtime_error` like so:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

class SomeEx : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    SomeEx(const std::string& msg) : runtime_error(msg) { }
};
```

Said `msg` will always be something like "invalid type ID 43". Is there any way to build that "what string" with another constructor (or another method) so that I provide only the integer type ID? Something like:

```
SomeEx(unsigned int id) {
    // set what string to ("invalid type ID " + id)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static std::string get_message(unsigned int id) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "invalid type ID " << id;
    return ss.str();
}
SomeEx(unsigned int id) 
    : runtime_error(get_message(id)) 
{}
```

unrelated: the reason we have string `.what()` is so that people STOP USING ERROR NUMBERS.

Comment: BTW `id` is not an error ID here, it's an application-specific ID. But see https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/07/12/your-own-error-code/ for arguments in favour of error codes!

Comment: That blog appears to be "how to", and at a glance, I don't see any arguments in it in favor of using error codes. The majority of it appears to be "if I'm using a library that uses error codes, how do I convert these to proper exceptions instead."

Answer (score 3):

Sure: `SomeEx(unsigned int id) : runtime_error(std::to_string(id)) { }`

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert the number into a string then you can simply append them:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

std::string BuildMessage(std::string const&  msg, int x)
{
    std::string result(msg);

    // Build your string here
    return result;
}

class SomeEx : public std::runtime_error
{
    public:
        SomeEx(const std::string& msg)
            : runtime_error(BuildMessage(msg, id)) { }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Mooing Duck's answer that nowadays you can use a lambda and directly call it as such:

```
SomeEx(unsigned int id) :
    std::runtime_error {
        [](const auto id) {
            std::ostringstream ss;

            ss << "invalid type ID " << id;
            return ss.str();
        }(id)
    }
{
}
```